# Uninstall USB storage device driver [USBSTOR.*]

Tags: windows-xp, usb

How do I remove the USB storage device driver from Windows XP, such that the next time a USB storage device is plugged in the Plug-and-Play infrastructure will install the driver before mounting the device? I tried deleting USBSTOR.SYS, but Windows automagically restores it a few seconds later.

**Background**

I want to use [MS KB 823732](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823732) to temporarily USB storage devices by setting the `HKLM\...\Services\UsbStor` registry key to "4". However, [this article](http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/windows/disable_usb_sticks) states that this only works **if a USB storage device is already installed on the PC**.

If a USB storage device is NOT already installed then:

> Windows' plug & play subsystem
>   automatically resets the Start value
>   to 3 (Manual) when it installs USBSTOR
>   after a USB storage device is plugged
>   in for the first time

I want to test my application's behavior in the case that a USB storage drive is not installed, but I don't know how  what to remove to do that.

Comment: You asked a really similar questions recently. What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: @geocar: My other question was targeted at identifying different options for programmatically restricting access to USB storage devices. This question deals with _one_ of those options in particular. In this question, I ask about to reproducing a system state in which a USB storage drive is not yet installed. Are my questions unclear? I haven't worn my sysadmin hat in over 6 years, so if I'm not making any sense please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

> I ask about to reproducing a system state in which a USB storage drive is not yet installed.

Then start by making a system like that.

If you can use a virtual machine, then make the system in the virtual machine. Most virtual machines support snapshotting, which can be used to "roll the whole system back".

Also: VMWare (for example) has an option to use the host's usb devices directly with the guest; Qemu has a `-usbdevice disk:file.img` for simulating a usb "disk".

If you cannot use a virtual machine, You can then use [System Restore](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/systemrestore.mspx) to checkpoint (and roll back) to your hardware configuration.

I don't recommend this if you're developing on the system that you're testing on. System Restore isn't very reliable. If you cannot afford a legitimate copy of Microsoft Windows, you can still download a copy of [Windows PE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2&displaylang=en) for no-cost.